# Error want to GET data after POST - nodejs, mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, jwt

I'm new in node.js and mysql. Today, I'm trying to make API that connect to db and now I'm having an issue.

After register (method: POST), I can't see all data (method: GET). Please take a look at the error:

on **console**:

```js
Server listening on port 3001
C:\...\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:526:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\...\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\...\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12) 
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\...\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15) 
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\...\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:158:21) 
    at response (C:\...\src\controllers\user.js:93:9)
    at C:\...\src\controllers\user.js:11:20
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\...\src\models\user.js:74:36)
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\...\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)   
    at Query._callback (C:\...\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:488:16) {   
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
```

on **Postman**
[image]

And if it can help you to help me, this is my code:

**userModel**

```js
const newUser = (a=null, b=null, c=null, d=null, e=null, f=null, g=null, cb=()=>{}) => {
    const qEmp = "INSERT INTO -- VALUE (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
    const qUsr = "INSERT INTO - VALUE (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
    const iEmp = [null, a, b, c, d]
    const iUsr = [null, e, f, g, 2]
    try {
        conn.query(qEmp, iEmp, 
        function (error, result, fields) {
            if (error){
                console.log("ERROR - newUser.fist: " + error);
                return cb("Internal Server Error", null)
            } else { 
                conn.query(qUsr, iUsr,
                        function (error, result, fields) {
                            if (error){
                                console.log("ERROR - newUser.second: " + error);
                                return cb("Internal Server Error", null)
                            }
                            return cb(null, result)
                        }
                    )
            }
            return cb(null, result)
        }) 
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("ERROR - catch: " + err);
        return cb("Internal Server Error", null)
    }
}
```

**on controller**

```js
exports.register = (req, res) => {
    const { a, b, c, d, e, f, g } = req.body
    try {
        userModel.newUser(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, (error, userData) => {
            if (error) return res.status(500).send({error})
            return response(res, 200, "Success", userData)
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("ERROR: addUser.catch = ");
        return res.status(500).send({error: "Internal Server Error"})
    }
}
```

my **response function**

```js
const response = (res, code, message, data) => {
    res.send({
        code,
        message,
        data
    })
}
```

If you see something wrong on my code, please tell me right away and (if you can (please)) tell me how to fix it. Thank you! Have a nice day!

Comment: I would recommend to use async/await for better code control, instead of callbacks.Nevertheless, can you post the gist of what response function does? This error usually means that the headers are being set after the response is sent using res.write/res.send/res.json/etc. I suspect something is going on in the response function.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late answer @SatyaKalluri . I added my response function. Also,  so, is it okay change it to async/await? Because I thought the only think this code to work is use callback

Comment: UPDATE -- @SatyaKalluri Oke, I've tried using async/await instead callback. but, do you know how to stop the function? because mine cannot stop sending request on postman. i know it's because i comment the callback, but yest, idk how to stop it. Thankies!

Answer (score 0):

So, I have my own answer. I just need to delete two callbacks

```js
const newUser = (a=null, b=null, c=null, d=null, e=null, f=null, g=null, cb=()=>{}) => {
    const qEmp = "INSERT INTO -- VALUE (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
    const qUsr = "INSERT INTO - VALUE (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
    const iEmp = [null, a, b, c, d]
    const iUsr = [null, e, f, g, 2]
    try {
        conn.query(qEmp, iEmp, 
        function (error, result, fields) {
            if (error){
                console.log("ERROR - newUser.fist: " + error);
                return cb("Internal Server Error", null)
            } else { 
                conn.query(qUsr, iUsr,
                        function (error, result, fields) {
                            if (error){
                                console.log("ERROR - newUser.second: " + error);
                            }
                        }
                    )
            }
            return cb(null, result)
        }) 
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("ERROR - catch: " + err);
        return cb("Internal Server Error", null)
    }
}
```

And my regis fom work well :)